# Properly Display Data in Google Charts

Tags: python, pandas, google-visualization

I am trying to visualize a large sum of data in google charts with a table exported from CSV files. Here is what my table looks like (**table is in pandas as df**):

```
name | date | location | counta | countb
Joe  | 2013 | USA      | 13     | 15
Jack | 2015 | Spain    | 21     | 5
Carl | 2013 | Russia   | 2      | 1
Joe  | 2015 | USA      | 42     | 9
Carl | 2015 | Russia   | 3      | 23
```

First thing I did was do a pivot

```
df = df.pivot_table(value = ['counta', countb'], index = ['date', 'location'], columns='name'
```

Returned this:

```
.....|.....   | Joe    | Joe    | Jack   | Jack   | Carl   | Carl 
date |location| counta | countb | counta | countb | counta | countb
2013 | USA    | 13     | 15     | 0      |0       | 0      | 0 
2013 | Russia | 0      | 0      | 0      |0       | 2      | 1 
2013 | Spain  | 0      | 0      | 0      |0       | 0      | 0 
2014 | USA    | 0      | 0      | 0      |0       | 0      | 0 
2014 | Russia | 0      | 0      | 0      |0       | 0      | 0 
2014 | Spain  | 0      | 0      | 0      |0       | 0      | 0 
2015 | USA    | 42     | 9      | 0      |0       | 0      | 0 
2015 | Russia | 0      | 0      | 0      |0       | 3      | 23 
2015 | Spain  | 0      | 0      | 21     |5       | 0      | 0
```

saving new `df` to csv file:

```
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

How do I get google charts to display:

- Date as an x-axis
- The names (Joe, Jack, and Carl) to each have separate boxes to show on the menu(below):[image] As you hover over a bar on the combo chart this is shown.  When I do this on google charts, I can do everything except make the part on the image above say what name the box belongs to. Instead of the name it is a date. Any help would be appreciated.

Question: Would it be possible to concat(name, counta) and concat(name, countb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's flatten columns with:

```
#You might need to swaplevel first
df1 = df1.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
```